# Introducing Autofac into an existing application

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Let's say that there is a graph of project dependencies that looks like this.

```
Assembly       Common    Shared     HR *          Accounting *     
----           ---       ----       ----          ----             
Dependency               Common     Common        Common           
                                    Shared        Shared           
                                    Accounting


Main              Warehouse *
---               -----
Common            Common
Shared            Shared
HR                HR
Accounting        Accounting
Warehouse
```

Projects marked with asterisk have Forms which can be displayed and are activated on demand via reflection from Main project.

What is the proper way of configuring Autofac container? Because, ideally, if I only use Accounting, I don't want to load HR and Warehouse assemblies.

Should I use Modules, or perhaps nested scopes? As you can see it's a bit confusing for me.

Comment: While it doesn't directly address this specific issue, there is an Autofac page on integration into existing applications that may give you some ideas. https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ExistingApplications

Comment: @Travis I had read most of the wiki before posting, and while it is otherwise very informative, I wasn't able to figure out solution for this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Autofac is not in the business of managing project dependencies so you may be looking in the wrong place.

Now, if you're really just asking how to resolve a dependency in one place from another, then my preference is to create another project called "Composition" and put a series of Modules there to describe your dependencies.

Comment: Wouldn't that invalidate the goal of loading assemblies on demand?

Comment: Autofac is not about "loading assemblies".  Rather, it's purpose is to resolve dependencies and manage instance lifetimes.  This about a service "MyService" that has a dependency on a repository "IMyRepository".  You would fulfill that required dependency, perhaps, by creating a constructor that takes an IMyRepository.  Then, using autofac, you would configure the container to resolve some particular kind of IMyRepository to use when you get a MyService from the container.  Autofac will take care of the lifetimes. None of this depends on project structure.